# How do browsers change font-weight if it's not present in the current font?

Tags: html, css, algorithm, browser, fonts

Say I have a web font with different font-weights as different files for each weight. When I change different weight in CSS, I suppose it looks for a respective font file that is associated with that font-weight. All works as intended.

Now, if I have another font, which has no different font-weights in it, then I again set different font-weight in my stylesheet, and see font-weight change in browser.

So, I wonder, how is in charge of calculating how font should look with a missing font-weight? Is it something what browsers try to guess using some algorithms? If so, do I still need other font-weight files? Or, how reliable are these algorithms through different browsers?

Comment: The CSS3 spec accounts for such cases [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-fonts/#font-weight-prop), but note that much of the browser behavior it describes is not normative other than mapping to nearby existing typefaces.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As mentioned by @BoltClock in a comment, this is described in CSS Fonts Module Level 3 CR, section 3.2 [Font weight: the font-weight property](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-fonts/#font-weight-prop) and in 5.2 [Matching font styles](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-fonts/#font-style-matching), but it does not define all the details, and browser behavior may vary.

The basic principle is that a typeface with the given font weight is used. For most fonts, only normal (regular, 400) and bold (700) typeface are available, perhaps only normal. In that case, all typefaces smaller than normal as well as 500 are mapped to normal, and 600, 800, and 900 are mapped to bold.

If bold typeface is not available but bolding is requested for (by `font-weight` set to 600 or larger), the browser *may* use algorithmic (synthetic) bolding on the normal typeface. In theory, this depends on the `font-synthesis` property, but it has not been implemented yet, so it depends on the browser.

Test page (assumes the availability of Lucida Sans Unicode, a common font in Windows, with just normal typeface):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<title>Test</title>
<style>
* { font-family: Lucida Sans Unicode }
</style>
<p>Hello world
<p style="font-weight: 600">Hello world
<p style="font-weight: 700">Hello world
<p style="font-weight: 800">Hello world
```

Firefox and IE show the paragraphs except the first one in synthetic bold (faux bold), whereas Chrome shows only the last two that way, i.e. does not map 600 to bold but to normal.

Generally, synthetic bold is frowned upon by typographers, for good reasons. It may however produce acceptable results for such sans-serif fonts that have little or no variation in stroke width, such as Lucida Sans Unicode or Arial Unicode MS.

Answer (score 2):

Answer from this [link](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/font-weight/):

> The font-weight property accepts either a keyword value or predefined
>   numeric value. The available keywords are:
>
> normal bold bolder lighter The available numeric values are:
>
> 100 200 300 400 500 600 700 800 900 The keyword value normal maps to
>   the numeric value 400 and the value bold maps to 700.
>
> In order to see any effect using values other than 400 or 700, the
>   font being used must have built-in faces that match those specified
>   weights.
>
> If a font has a bold ("700") or normal ("400") version as part of the
>   font family, the browser will use that. **If those are not available,
>   the browser will mimic its own bold or normal version of the font**. It
>   will not mimic the other unavailable weights. Fonts often use names
>   like "Regular" and "Light" to identify any alternate font weights.

Comment: The page quoted is neither official nor accurate.

Answer (score 1):

If an appropriate font family is not found, the browser will basically guess. And guessing means you'll get inferior quality rendering, and inconsistent results across browsers. So if at all possible, you really should try to not let this happen:

ref: http://alistapart.com/article/say-no-to-faux-bold

Comment: No, browsers won’t guess. They do what they have been programmed to do, and this not involve heuristics in this case. What you say about inferior quality and inconsistent results is true, but does not answer the question.